# Do you want hats?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

**EDIT:** Please provide feedback on the [Winter Bash](http://winterba.sh/) over on Meta Stack Overflow:

- [What do you think of Winter Bash?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161188/what-do-you-think-of-winter-bash)

---

If you participated in [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), you may have noticed the [Holiday 2011 Hat Dash](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/) last year. It was an event where users could earn "hats" for their gravatars by completing various tasks. It's a somewhat specialized form of a badge in that triggering certain actions would unlock a hat.

[image: hats]

Stack Exchange is running the [promotion](http://stackexchange.com/promos/2/hat-dash) again, but this time extending the event to all sites. However, we as a site have to **opt-in** in order to participate. This is completely optional, and there is no obligation to partake in this event at all. If we do choose to participate **individual users can choose to opt-out** via an "I hate hats" option that will be available.

Since Fitness.SE has had some very good activity over the past few months, this perhaps would be a fun thing for users and engage the community some more.

If you feel like this is a good idea, please voice your opinion. A response for the site will have to be in by **November 28, 2012** if we want to participate. No response automatically means that we will opt-out of the event.

Comment: Absolutely we want hats!

Comment: Me too! (but I can't upvote myself)

Comment: Looks like a good idea to get people involved in areas they never have been before.

Comment: I thought this was about real hats :(

Comment: Aww, sorry to burst your bubble. But that might not be a bad idea for SE swag. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing a good number of votes and positive responses here so far, so I've sent in the **opt-in** response to the Stack Exchange team. Thanks for the feedback!